# Deepl API Document Translation English target language problem

Tags: c#, translation, translate, deepl

```
try
{
    await translator.TranslateDocumentAsync(
          new FileInfo("deneemq11.docx"),
          new FileInfo("deneemq11(11).docx"),
          "TR",
          "EN",
          new DocumentTranslateOptions { Formality = Formality.More });
}
catch (DocumentTranslationException exception)
{
    // If the error occurs *after* upload, the DocumentHandle will contain the document ID and key
    if (exception.DocumentHandle != null)
    {
        var handle = exception.DocumentHandle.Value;
        MessageBox.Show($"Document ID: {handle.DocumentId}, Document key: {handle.DocumentKey}");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error occurred during document upload: {exception.Message}");
    }
}
```

I used "EN" for target language but it gave me some errors then I used EN-GB for target language:

```
try
{
    await translator.TranslateDocumentAsync(
          new FileInfo("deneemq11.docx"),
          new FileInfo("deneemq11(11).docx"),
          "TR",
          "EN-GB",
          new DocumentTranslateOptions { Formality = Formality.More });
}
catch (DocumentTranslationException exception)
{
    // If the error occurs *after* upload, the DocumentHandle will contain the document ID and key
    if (exception.DocumentHandle != null)
    {
        var handle = exception.DocumentHandle.Value;
        MessageBox.Show($"Document ID: {handle.DocumentId}, Document key: {handle.DocumentKey}");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error occurred during document upload: {exception.Message}");
    }
}
```

and it says formality is not supported for given target_lang

What do I need to enter for target language to become English

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting to translate with a certain level of formality (`new DocumentTranslateOptions { Formality = Formality.More }` in your code). However, not all languages support setting a formality (e.g. some non-English languages like German have a formal and an informal version of "you"). You can call the [languages endpoint](https://developers.deepl.com/docs/api-reference/languages) to get up-to-date information which languages these are - British English currently does not support formality, so you need to change your code to exclude this formality option:

```java
try
{
    await translator.TranslateDocumentAsync(
          new FileInfo("deneemq11.docx"),
          new FileInfo("deneemq11(11).docx"),
          "TR",
          "EN-GB");
}
catch (DocumentTranslationException exception)
{
    // If the error occurs *after* upload, the DocumentHandle will contain the document ID and key
    if (exception.DocumentHandle != null)
    {
        var handle = exception.DocumentHandle.Value;
        MessageBox.Show($"Document ID: {handle.DocumentId}, Document key: {handle.DocumentKey}");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error occurred during document upload: {exception.Message}");
    }
}
```

You can find more information in the official docs [here](https://developers.deepl.com/docs/api-reference/translate#request-body-descriptions).